# Launch An Activity Afresh(Don't Retain State) On A Notification Click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I want to launch an Activity(Afresh, Without any previously retained state) on a notification click. IF this Activity is already in the stack, bring this to top but without any previous state.

So Far i have tried setting Flags to Passed Intent.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|INTENT.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
```

But They Don't serve the purpose. Any suggestions how i could achieve this.

Comment: what is the your problem then?

Comment: I Want To Start The Activity without Retaining Any Previous State. These Flags do bring the Activity To Foreground but Its Previous state is retained.I want to loose the Activity Data  as if the Activity is Starting Afresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` from your launch this should restart the activity.

Specifying `|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the launch flags causes the existing instance to be reused. If you remove it the existing instance will be finished and a new instance will be launched.

Comment: so i just have to use intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) & Nothing Else elsewhere is it?

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go.

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

to open application in anystate.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
```

startActivity(LaunchIntent);

Comment: AS i have said they do bring the activity to foreground if one exists,or start a new one But I dont want to Retain the state of This Activity. IT should be started a fresh.

Comment: It already Start with a fresh state. What do you exactly mean by dont want to retain the state you just want to jump into the app no matter what state it is on is this what you want ?

Comment: Try this. And use your package name. on notification click this will open up your app no matter what state it is on and will do a full refresh if the app is not started wont take you to a specific activity. 'code' Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);